# AJAX post method failing in Django: 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm using jQuery in my program to send POST requests to my database to log user actions in a client-side Javascript game, hosted on a Django framework. I *had* been getting 403 errors until I added

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
```

with the appropriately-populated `csrftoken` value, but instead of happily magically working as promised, I'm now getting a 404 error when I try to `$.post()`.

Preemptively: yes, the URL that the error message claims is a 404 does load if I copy and paste it into the address bar.

urls.py (partial, omitted irrelevant pages):

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^init/$', views.init, name='init'),
    url(r'^log/$', views.log, name='log')
]
```

views.py (partial, omitted irrelevant views):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Partnership, RunLog

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html')

def init(request):
    [...]
    return render(request, 'mysite/init.html', args)

def log(request):
    """ This is for logging actions within the blockly-game interface.
        It is called by jQuery code in maze.js every time the user pushes
        the Run button, so we can see how they're doing.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        code = request.POST['usercode']
        status = request.POST['status']
        ps = get_object_or_404(Partnership, name=request.POST['ps'])
        runlog = RunLog.objects.create_runlog(ps.name, status, code)
        runlog.save()
    return HttpResponse('x')
```

From maze.js:

```
console.log(ps);            // works as expected
console.log(Maze.result);   // works as expected
console.log(code);          // works as expected
console.log(csrftoken)      // works as expected

// this gives a 404 with csrfmiddlewaretoken; 403 without
$.post('/mysite/log/',
  {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
      ps: path,
      status: Maze.result,
      usercode: code
  }
);
```

Also verified that I correctly added the RunLog model to my database, and it shows up in my admin view with no entries.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The Python code raises a 404 if no Partnership with that name is found. So what is being sent as the `ps` value? Where does `path` come from?

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. Thank you.